# Are DUI checks more lenient in Napa County?

Tags: driving, alcohol, northern-california

Tourists typically don't go to [Napa County](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napa_County,_California) to drink water. I heard that DUI checks more lenient in Napa County than in other parts of California. Is that true?

Lenient ->  fewer checks, the actual enforced blood alcohol content is higher, and/or penalties are lower.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, unfortunately not authoritative enough source to ask there.

Comment: Tourists go to Napa Country to *taste* the wine. Tasting is done in very small quantities. I live near a couple of Canadian wine regions, and there's no leniency on DUI. Which is really good for the organizers of chauffered wine tasting tours.

Comment: They call the local police the "Napzis". They stakeout wine tastings. Their favorite targets are out of state plates and rental cars.

Comment: @pnuts I don't know, do you have a rental car?

Comment: I indeed use a rental car, but one can't see it's rented as rented from another individual)

Comment: Different country, different beverage. Drove out of Lightning Ridge in Australia - Opal mining town on edge of outback - desert road to there from ?Walgate?. Far from "normal" civilisation. Lo and behold 3 friendlyish coppers (one at least a woman) manning a breath test check point. In the middle (approx) of a desert? We joked with them , were duly breath tested without problems and asked what they were doing here so far from home etc. They told us that there was  rugby reunion in the town. Oh. There were indeed liable tro be some sorry reunionees staggering past this point later in the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is highly unlikely. [Google](http://www.duiblock.com/dui_checkpoint_locations/california/napa/) turns up a historical list of DUI checkpoints. Note that holiday periods are covered.

It is very bad publicity for a winery if someone over-tastes, drives out of the lot, and has a DUI accident. I don't think there is any objection from them on strict enforcement.

Comment: Downvote? Wow. Sorry to rain on your DUI parade. I don't think you get the local culture is not DUI-friendly. A patron of a recent wine fair in Livermore (different California wine-growing area) got bombed, drove recklessly on the way home, killed two bystanders, and he is being prosecuted for *murder* as opposed to the "usual" vehicular manslaughter. http://www.sfgate.com/crime/article/Prosecutors-Speeder-who-killed-2-after-wine-fest-6279707.php"

Comment: See also http://www.cityofnapa.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1452:napa-pd-receives-grant-for-dui-enforcement&catid=52:latest&Itemid=30